# How to install Ubuntu Core (2 versions) into separated hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, ubuntu-core

I want to install 2 Ubuntu core distributions to 2 separated hard drives in one PC.
I tried but there is only one distribution shown in the boot sequence menu.
How can we change the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg?